# Review of singlely linked list C

Tags: c, linked-list

I posted a couple of weeks ago with a [double linked list](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32854/critique-a-beginners-linked-list-implementation).  It was recommended that I rewrite the code as a singlely linked list and replace the recursive parts with loops.

I've gone ahead and made several edits and was hoping to get another critique of the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


struct file {
    int fd;
    struct file *next;
};

struct file *create_head(void) {
    struct file *first_link = malloc ( sizeof *first_link );
    return first_link;
}

void insert(struct file *node, int val) {
    while (node->next != NULL) {
        node = node->next;
    }
    struct file *tail = malloc ( sizeof *tail );
    node->next = tail;
    tail->fd = val;
    tail->next = NULL;
}

int delete(struct file *node, int val) {
    struct file *prev;
    while (node->fd != val) {
        if(!(node->next)) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            prev = node;    
            node = node->next;
        } 
    }
    prev->next = node->next;
    free(node);       
    return 0;
}

int locate(struct file *node, int val) {
    while (node->fd != val) {
        if (!(node->next)) {       
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            node = node->next;
        }        
    }
    printf ("Value %d in list\n", val);
    return 0;
}

void dump(struct file *node) {
    while (node->next) {
        printf ("Node: %d\n", node->fd);
        node = node->next;
    }
    printf ("Node: %d\n", node->fd); 
}

int get_choice(void) {
    int choice;
    int val;
    struct file *head = NULL;
    while ( true ) {
        printf ("\n[Choices - Insert=1, Delete=2, Locate=3, Dump=4, Exit=5]\n");
        printf ("\nEnter selection: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch (choice) {
            case (1): 
                printf ("Enter value: ");
                scanf ("%d", &val);
                if (!(head)) {
                    head = create_head();
                    head->fd = val;
                    head->next = NULL;
                }
                else {
                    insert(head, val);
                }
                break;
            case (2):
                if (head) { 
                    printf ("Enter value: ");
                    scanf ("%d", &val); 
                    if (head->fd == val && head->next == NULL) {
                        head = NULL;    
                    }
                    else if (head->fd == val && head->next != NULL) {
                        free (head);
                        head = head->next;
                    }
                    else if (delete(head, val) == 1) {                
                        printf ("Value %d not in list\n", val);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    printf ("List is empty!\n");
                }
                break;
            case (3): 
                if (head) {
                    printf ("Enter value: ");
                    scanf ("%d", &val); 
                    if (locate(head, val) == 1) {
                        printf ("Value %d not in list\n", val);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    printf ("List is empty!\n");
                }
                break;
            case (4): 
                if (head) { 
                    dump(head);
                }
                else {
                    printf ("Nothing to dump!\n");
                }
                break;
            case (5): 
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    printf ("\nSingle Linked List: \n");
    get_choice();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Stylistic/Function**

1. Your list holds values of type `int` yet you named the node type very specific in relation to file descriptors which will be a bit weird if you make a list of lets say prime numbers you want to operate on. Consider renaming your node type to something more generic rather than `file` (especially sincere there is a `FILE` type in `<stdio.h>`)
2. Your `insert` method actually doesn't insert an element, it appends it to the end so it should be named `append`.
3. `delete` doesn't work when the node you want to delete is `head`. I know you handle that case separately in `get_choice` but it's still bad that the caller has to know that fact. It also clutters the code with lots of special handling.
4. `dump` is a bit weird: It skips the first one, then prints all following nodes in order and then prints the first one. So while it prints out all nodes I'd say it's still unexpected from a usage point of view.
5. None of your methods can deal with the fact if `NULL` is being passed in.
6. If you `typedef` your structs then you can save some typing work.

**Structural/Design**

1. Your list does not have a nice API to use. You can see that in `get_choice` which is cluttered with handling of many special cases.
2. Some methods like `insert` (`size/length` would be a different candidate) are inefficient as you have to iterate the entire list first. You could avoid that by keeping a separate `tail` pointer.

I suggest you create a list object which holds `head`, `tail` and possibly `length` of the list and all your methods should operate on an object of that list type rather than nodes. Something along these lines:

```
typedef struct node_
{
    int value;
    struct node *next;
} node;

typedef struct list_
{
    struct node *head;
    struct node *tail;
    int length;
} list;
```

And then define some methods to operate on:

```
// creates a new empty list
list *new_list()
{
}

// deletes the list and all the nodes
void delete_list(list *l)
{
}

// appends new value to the list
void append(list *l, int value)
{
}

// insert a value at a given position
void insert(list *l, int value, int position)
{
}

// deletes the first node with the given value from the list
// return 1 if node found and deleted, 0 otherwise
int delete_item(list *l, int value)
{
}

// returns the first node with the given value or NULL if not found
node *find(list *l, int value)
{
}

// prints the content of the list
void print_list(list *l)
{
}
```

Your `get_choice` method would then look like this:

```
int get_choice(void) {
    int choice;
    int val;
    list *myList = new_list();
    while ( true ) {
        printf ("\n[Choices - Insert=1, Delete=2, Locate=3, Dump=4, Exit=5]\n");
        printf ("\nEnter selection: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch (choice) {
            case (1): 
                printf ("Enter value: ");
                scanf ("%d", &val);
                append(myList, val);
                break;
            case (2):
                if (myList->length > 0) { 
                    printf ("Enter value: ");
                    scanf ("%d", &val); 
                    if (!delete_item(myList, val))
                    {               
                        printf ("Value %d not in list\n", val);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    printf ("List is empty!\n");
                }
                break;
            case (3): 
                if (myList->length > 0) {
                    printf ("Enter value: ");
                    scanf ("%d", &val); 
                    if (find(myList, val) == NULL) {
                        printf ("Value %d not in list\n", val);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    printf ("List is empty!\n");
                }
                break;
            case (4): 
                if (myList->length > 0) { 
                    print_list(myList);
                }
                else {
                    printf ("Nothing to dump!\n");
                }
                break;
            case (5): 
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: these points are all very enlightening.  Especially testing for NULL and having the separate list to track.